# using timedelay function in javascript

Tags: javascript, impactjs

I am trying to set my localStorage key values after a certain condition becomes true but wait for 2 seconds before it can update the localStorage key value

This is what I am trying to do but it throws an exception and when it tries to set the localStorage value

```
if(tempArray.length <= 0){                               
   setTimeout(function(){
       this.storage.set(achkey,1);                              
   },2000);                                   
}
```

The exception says variable achkey undefined though I can use it outside the setTimeout function. How do I go about implementing the delay and setting values inside correctly? I am using ImpactJS engine which uses javascript. I am also using a plugin for my localStorage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cache `this`. Once you enter the `setTimeout`'s anonymous function, `this` now refers to the scope of the function that you just declared.

```
if(tempArray.length <= 0){                               
   var self = this; // Cache the current scope's `this`
   setTimeout(function(){
       self.storage.set(achkey,1);                              
   },2000);                                   
}
```